# Unable to connect to a exposed gRPC URL by Go code

Tags: go, postman, grpc

I have written a gRPC client in Go, which is trying to connect a gRPC server.
The gRPC server exposed by other team, provided a URL --> catalogue-go.domain.dev

The gRPC URL working fine, getting the response properly when I am calling server using a [Postman](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/postman/info) gRPC client, but when I call the server URL in code, it shows the below error:

> 2023-11-24T10:53:52.452+0530    ERROR    utils/validation.go:256    received error from Catalogue gRPC server    {"err": "rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing: dial tcp: address catalogue-go.domain.dev""}

```
// Establish gRPC connection
ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 5*time.Second) // Waiting time(timeout)
defer cancel()
cataloguegRPCUrl := os.Getenv("CATALOGUE_GRPC_DOMAIN")
conn, err := grpc.DialContext(ctx, cataloguegRPCUrl, grpc.WithTransportCredentials(insecure.NewCredentials()))
if err != nil {
    zap.L().Error("Error setting up GRPC connection", zap.Reflect("err", err.Error()))
    return nil, errors.New(constant.SomethingWentWrong)
} else {
    zap.L().Info("Connection established with Catalogue GRPC server")
}
defer conn.Close()

// Connection established
client := numbers.NewNumberSubscriptionServiceClient(conn)

// Prepare gRPC metadata
md := metadata.New(
    map[string]string {
        // Required meta data added here
    })
ctx = metadata.NewOutgoingContext(ctx, md)

// Prepare input for gRPC call
inputPhoneNumber := numbers.ManageNumberRequest {
    Number: []string {
        number,
    },
}

// Calling the gRPC
zap.L().Debug("Request made to Catalogue gRPC", zap.String("cataloguegRPCUrl", cataloguegRPCUrl), zap.Reflect("metadata", md), zap.Reflect("input phone number", inputPhoneNumber.Number))
serverResponse, err := client.ManageNumbers(ctx, &inputPhoneNumber)
if err != nil {
    zap.L().Error("received error from Catalogue gRPC server", zap.Reflect("err", err.Error()))
    return nil, errors.New(constant.SomethingWentWrong)
}
zap.L().Debug("catalogue gRPC returned response", zap.Reflect("response", serverResponse))
```

The same code was working when I cloned the gRPC server and ran it on my machine locally. The code is working superbly, getting a response, but the exposed gRPC URL is not working in code, although the Postman gRPC client is getting a response. What am I missing here?

Comment: Is the gRPC service endpoint (`catalogue-go.domain.dev`) secure or insecure? This difference may be obscured by Postman (I'm unfamiliar with Postman). Your Go code expects the endpoint to be insecure (`insecure.NewCredentials()`).